# Language neutral pages not showing all menu items

Tags: drupal, internationalization, translation, multilingual

After translating some pages and keeping some pages "Language Neutral" the primary links menu behaves differently on different pages. Specifically, on pages set as Japanese, it shows all menu items (Japanese and Language Neutral), but on Language Neutral, it shows only Language Neutral pages (note in Screencast below the language neutral pages have been translated using String Translation module so they seem to be in Japanese but are not).

Here's an example: http://screencast.com/t/uJvF3j4n

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution! Just need...

Site configuration > Languages > Multilingual system > All content. No language conditions apply.